# How to append new item into serialized xml data without deserialize old data?

Tags: c#, list, xml-serialization

Normally, I use the following code to serialize object to XML file. Everyday, I have about 100-1000 new items to be added into this list in different period of time.

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestModel>));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, list);
```

How to append new item into serialized xml data without deserialize old data?

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can serialize objecto to memory and append to existing file. Also take a look at MS article [Efficient Techniques for Modifying Large XML Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx) which shows two techniques both applicable in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of doing what you want using only the `XmlSerializer` that I can think of, but with a little bit of extra work this is possible.

A simple approach to this would be to serialize the list for the first item(s) of the day - as your existing code does. When new data comes in, you can now open the saved xml using an `XmlDocument` and append the serialization of one single item at a time.

One thing to note is that if the resulting xml is extremely big, the XmlDocument may grow very large (and may be slow or even cause OutOfMemoryExceptions as Pavel Kyments notes in a comment), in this case you may want to investigate `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` to append the xml serially. However the overall approach would remain the same (open->serialize your new item->append the generated xml->resave)

[**EDIT** - changed code sample to show chained `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter`, rather than `XmlDocument` approach]

Something along these lines:

```
public static void AppendToXml(
    Stream xmlSource,             // your existing xml - could be from a file, etc
    Stream updatedXmlDestination, // your target xml, could be a different file
    string rootElementName,       // the root element name of your list, e.g. TestModels
    TestModel itemToAppend)       // the item to append
{
    var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true, IndentChars = " " };
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlSource))
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(updatedXmlDestination, writerSettings))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI);
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                        {
                            writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Prefix, reader.LocalName, reader.NamespaceURI, reader.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    if (reader.IsEmptyElement) 
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    if (reader.Name == rootElementName)
                    {
                        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestModel));
                        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                        ns.Add("", "");
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, itemToAppend, ns);
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteRaw(SecurityElement.Escape(reader.Value));
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                    writer.WriteCData(reader.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** you may want to add support for other node types (omitted here for brevity), such as Whitespace, Comments, Processing Instructions, etc. These all follow the same pattern as CDATA above: put a case in, call the appropriate writer method.

With this updated approach - you never have more than a small amount in memory at any given time.

Comment: I was just typing the same thing. Use an XmlReader or or one of the other Xml classes to manipulate the XML directly. It's not the best/easiest solution, which would be to deserialize it first, but we'll assume you've already that since you're here.

Comment: Note: on realy large documents XmlDocument will fail because it loads whole document to memory

Comment: @PavelKymets - indeed. As mentioned above - in this case a serial approach using `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter` may be preferable.

Comment: Why the downvote? I've just posted a testing and working solution, and mentioned the limitations of this approach and how else it might be attempted if this does not suffice. Surely an actual down vote is a bit harsh?

Comment: I think your code doesn't change anything because system still need to parse all XML tag into XML document. If there are more than 1k items in XML file, it should take some time to parse it.

Comment: Updated code sample to use the read/writer approach I alluded to in the text. Now you only ever have a small amount in memory at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. You want to perform random access to a block of data that is **serialized** and **deserialized**, so it has to be accessed sequentially.
Maybe you can modify directly the XML document, which will be faster, but you'll be losing the facilities of using a serialized/deserialized object tree, which is much more easy to manipulate (add/remove objects, ...)